# consolidating multiple columns into one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df that has multiple columns that end in the same value. I want to consolidate columns into one final column. For example, any columns that end in '_1' should go into a new column labeled 'final_1'. The value in final_1 would be 1 if all values in '_1' are '1' and final_1 would be 0 if otherwise e.g., if there's at least one value that isn't '1' within the '_1' columns.

The original and final result dataframes are more clear if my explanation is not.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000003', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009'], 
              'RO_1': [1, 1, 4,1],
              'RO_2': [1, 0, 0,0],
              'RO_3': [1, 1, 1,1],
              'en_1': [1, 4, 1,1],
              'en_2': [1, 4, 1,0],
              'en_3': [1, 4, 4,0],
              'ao_1': [1, 4, 1,1],
              'ao_2': [1, 4, 1,0],
              'ao_3': [1, 4, 4,0] })

    KEY         RO_1    RO_2    RO_3    ao_1    ao_2    ao_3    en_1    en_2    en_3
0   100000003   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
2   100000009   4       0       1       1       1       4       1       1       4
3   100000009   1       0       1       1       0       0       1       0       0
```

Final result:

```
   KEY          RO_1    RO_2    RO_3    ao_1    ao_2    ao_3    en_1    en_2    en_3  Final1  Final2  Final3
0   100000003   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1     1       1       1
2   100000009   4       0       1       1       1       4       1       1       4     0       0       0
3   100000009   1       0       1       1       0       0       1       0       0     1       0       0
```

My current attempt. SInce there are 3 different columns I'm using a loop. then I'm combining the original df with the new frame (mc). But I am not getting anything different..

```
for i in range(1,4):
    mc = df.filter(regex='^_' + str(i)).isin([1]).astype(int).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_', 'Final'))
df= pd.concat([df, mc], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DSM has proposed a better option for splitting column names:

```
In [170]: cols = df.columns.drop('KEY')

In [171]: d = (df[cols]
                 .groupby(cols.str.split('_').str[-1], axis=1)
                 .all()
                 .astype(int)
                 .add_prefix('Final_'))

In [172]: df.join(d)
Out[172]:
         KEY  RO_1  RO_2  RO_3  ao_1  ao_2  ao_3  en_1  en_2  en_3  Final_1  Final_2  Final_3
0  100000003     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1        1        1        1
1  100000009     1     0     1     4     4     4     4     4     4        1        0        1
2  100000009     4     0     1     1     1     4     1     1     4        1        0        1
3  100000009     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0        1        0        0
```

or this solution from (c) @DSM and @piRSquared:

```
In [194]: df.join(df.drop('KEY', 1)
                    .eq(1) 
                    .groupby(lambda c: c.rsplit('_', 1)[1], 1)
                    .all().astype(int).add_prefix('Final'))
Out[194]:
         KEY  RO_1  RO_2  RO_3  ao_1  ao_2  ao_3  en_1  en_2  en_3  Final1  Final2  Final3
0  100000003     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       1       1       1
1  100000009     1     0     1     4     4     4     4     4     4       0       0       0
2  100000009     4     0     1     1     1     4     1     1     4       0       0       0
3  100000009     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0       1       0       0
```

Comment: Comparing his desired output and his code, I think OP is more after `(d==1).groupby(d.columns.str.split('_').str[-1], axis=1).all().astype(int)` (where as usual I've avoided the regex because I don't like them. :-)

Comment: You can also use  a `lambda` that gets applied to the index. `df.join(df.drop('KEY', 1).groupby(lambda c: c.rsplit('_', 1)[1], 1).all().astype(int).add_prefix('Final'))`

Comment: The more important point is that I interpret his "would be 1 if all values in '_1' are '1'" and `.isin([1])` to mean `==1`.  Compare his expected values with yours: he has a row of all 0s.

Comment: @DSM are you suggesting `df.join(df.drop('KEY', 1).eq(1).groupby(lambda c: c.rsplit('_', 1)[1], 1).all().astype(int).add_prefix('Final'))`

Comment: @DSM You are correctly interpreting. I left the .isin() just to see a solution for multiple conditions, but with the way I asked the question your response is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is predefined, then `numpy` provides an efficient solution:

```
n = 3
v = df.iloc[:,1:].values
v[v!=1] = 0

for i in range(1, n+1):
    df['Final'+str(i)] = (np.all(v[:, [i-1+n*k for k in range(n)]], axis=1)).astype(int)

#          KEY  RO_1  RO_2  RO_3  ao_1  ao_2  ao_3  en_1  en_2  en_3  Final1  \
# 0  100000003     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       1   
# 1  100000009     1     0     1     4     4     4     4     4     4       0   
# 2  100000009     4     0     1     1     1     4     1     1     4       0   
# 3  100000009     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0       1   

#    Final2  Final3  
# 0       1       1  
# 1       0       0  
# 2       0       0  
# 3       0       0
```